# Patterns for dealing with async APIs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, async-await

How do you deal with this common pattern I’ve run into myself a bunch in typescript?

```js
async RemoteCall(): Promise<Result> {
    var res: Result = await RPC()
    if (res) {
        return res
    }
}
```

Should I:

1. Make `Result` a more robust type? (e.g. has data and errors attributes)
2. Change the return value to `Promise<Result | undefined>`?
3. Fill in Result with default values / 0 initialized?
4. Something else?  Monads?

I'm unfamiliar with current best practices surrounding both Javascript and Typescript, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this may be more of a problem with how you're returning the promise from the function, I would think that it would normally be better to always return a promise here, and either resolve or reject the promise depending on the result of `RPC`. I'm guessing that'd look something like `return RPC().catch(*handle an error here*)`

Comment: Thanks @OliverRadini!  The promise isn't really my issue here though.  The bigger issue I have is just that when an API call fails, we're not going to have the data to construct the User object, and I don't want to do `{username: "", email: "", avatarURL: ""}` every time the call fails.

That is to say, regardless if we're returning the promise or not, how do you deal with that issue?

Perhaps making this about async was a red herring.  It's really about how best to handle errors

Comment: The thing is, handling errors in code that isn't doing I/O is relatively simple because the behavior is constrained, which is why I guess I made it about async.

Comment: If that's your issue, then it'd probably be a good idea to include some code to demonstrate that here. To me it seems like the best pattern would be to not attempt to construct a user at all if the call fails, but as I say, I can't really see your whole use case. What I can see though is that you have a function that will return `Promise<Result> | undefined` which is probably quite difficult to handle, as you can't, without several checks, await the response/use `then` etc.

Comment: I've been using Go so long that I forgot how useful generics can be.  This answer I found on reddit made the solution really eloquent by using Generics to achieve multiple return parameters.  No try/catch, no ignoring errors. :-)

https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/8l3ar6/error_handling_in_typescript/dzcnh9o/

Comment: That's a fine way of handling things, but surely if `RPC` throws an error, or you throw an error when it returns an invalid result, you can just `.catch` the promise? Unless you want to use `await` on the result, in which case you do need a `try/catch` which is slightly ugly

Comment: Hopefully throws are not common.  I may be wrong but I don't think most libraries are throwing except in unrecoverable cases.  I am `await`ing, but I'm still uncertain about why I would need to wrap in a try/catch block.  In the docs for the libraries that I'm currently `await`ing on (Apollo), it seems like they don't throw:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html

Comment: It's certainly quite common to have `.catch` on a promise, so my assumption is that it's also relatively common for libraries to throw. I'm not saying that's a good pattern, though, and with the setup which you have, I don't think you'd need to `catch`, as you'll always be getting something back which you can work with